# How do I check if a checkbox has been checked in another tab in tabcontrol

Tags: c#, wpf, checkbox, tabcontrol

so I am fairly new to the TabControl, and I've looked over some tutorial, read some posts and I cant find anything on how to check if a checkbox is checked in one tab and if a textbox has content in it, in another tab, I think it's called checking properties but I am not entirely sure.

So imaging you have this WPF witha  tabControl with two tabs and 1 button outside the tabControl.
The first tab containing 1 checkbox and the second tab containing a textbox

Now how were I to check if the checkbox is checked and if the `textbox.text != ""`

--UPDATE--
As I just found out, checkboxes are global aslong as they are in the same window and I asked fox how to do it if the textbox was in another window for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the `Name` property of your CheckBoxes to something unique and then use that to get correct CheckBox when you are checking it in your code behind.

Setting the Name looks like this in your XAML:

```
<CheckBox Name="myCheckBox" />
```

after that you can use code like this in your code behind to find out if your CheckBox has been checked:

```
if (myCheckBox.IsChecked) {
    Console.WriteLine("my checkbox is checked.");
}
```

To check if a CheckBox in another Window or UserControl is checked you can add a property to the Window that contains the CheckBox in question that you update whenever the CheckBoxes checked state changes.

```
public bool MyTextBoxIsChecked {get; set;}
```

Comment: So checkboxes used in tabs (doesnt matter which tab) are global?

Comment: Yes it is global for the UserControl or Window it is added to.

Comment: Oh! I'm glad you said that, what f Iwanted to use another window? Would you mind updating your answer with that in it aswell? If you got time ofc!

Comment: I can do that. Can you please update your question as well to contain that information? That will help others finding your question.

Comment: so would I just create a if(MyTextBoxIsChecked) ?

Comment: Basicyally yes, but it needs to look more like `if (myOtherWindow.MyTextBoxIsChecked)`

Comment: Dont we need to set ```MyTextBoxIsChecked``` to something? Because otherwise we're just checking if something is true or false but not actually checking what is true or false? Am I even making any sense here :lol:

Comment: @JonnyKhanas Yes you need to set the `MyTextBoxIsChecked` property whenever `myCheckBox` raises the `Checked` or `Unchecked` events. See the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.togglebutton.checked(v=vs.110).aspx) on how you can do that.

Answer (score 0):

As answered by FlyingFox, I assume that checkboxes are global.

```
<Checkbox Name="myCheckBox" />

private void myCheckBox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (myCheckBox.Checked)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("my checkbox is checked.");
    }
    else if (!myCheckBox.Checked)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("my checkbox is not checked."); 
    }
}
```

> Checking if textbox has Text or not:

```
if (textbox1.Text.Length > 0)
{
  Console.WriteLine("Textbox has text"); 
}
```